# Says my button for calculator should resolve but doesn't

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Button section says tk should resolve but doesn't. Also it doesn't recognize the frame variable in the brackets (trying to pack it in frame)

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg='SkyBlue1')
canvas.pack()
fnt = font.Font(family='Arial', size=60, weight=font.BOLD)
title = tk.Label(canvas, text="ProjX", bg='SkyBlue1', font=fnt)
title.pack()
root.configure(bg='CadetBlue1')
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='DeepSkyBlue2')
frame.place(relwidth='0.8', relheight='0.6', relx='0.1', rely='0.2'
calc = tk.Button( frame, text="Suvat Calculator", bg='SkyBlue1', font='Arial' )
calc.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not call `title.pack()` as its parent is canvas.  Use `canvas.create_window()` to put the label in the canvas or `canvas.create_text(...)` instead of `Label`.  Also missing ending `)` in `frame.place(...`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful